# Multilevel GridView in WPF

Tags: gridview, treeview, wpfdatagrid

I have been trying to search frantically for Nesting GridViews(4 levels). I have used Rowdetailstemplate for 2 levels for a different view but not beyond it.
Many articles have gridview inside a TreeView which is ok but I need my inner elements to have headers too. Something like this(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MasterDetail.aspx)

Many articles have gridviews inside treeview but with no headers. In this at eachlevel I want to add headers. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Above link is for ASP. I have got something like this for WPF GridViews((http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are special tools for it in WPF, and they are the [`ListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) and the [`BindingListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx), both declared as [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

Please take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/14/master-detail-data-binding-in-wpf-with-entity-framework.aspx), I am sure it will help you a lot.

In short, it should be declared:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="BlogsCollection" Source="{Binding Blogs}" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ArticlesCollection" 
    Source="{Binding Articles, Source={StaticResource BlogsCollection}}" />
```

I used it with a case like yours but I my DG's SelectionMode was set to one row, and it worked fine, donn't how it will behave in multiselection, but I am sure it could be worked out (maybe by setting the staticresource inside the details etmplate).